# Magento2: Customization code for display product name per store website

Tags: magento2

In our template, we display product name from attribute: custom_name

Below is the code:
list.phtml

```
<?php
                                $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getCustomName(), null, true);
                                ?>
                                <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                    <a class="product-item-link"
                                       href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                       $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                        $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getCustomName(), 'custom_name') ?>
                                    </a>
                                </strong>
```

What we need to do:

- if store code PL: display  custom_name_pl if empty attribute
  custom_name_pl display custom_name
- if store code EN:
  display custom_name_en
- if empty attribute custom_name_en display
  custom_name
- if store code DE: display custom_name_de if empty
  attribute custom_name_de display custom_name
- if store code CZ:
  display custom_name_cz
- if empty attribute custom_name_cz display
  custom_name

here is similar code we use for description:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
if($_code == "short_description") {
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCode();

if($storeCode == "en") {
$_call = 'getEnglishShortDescription';
$_code == "english_short_description";
}

if($storeCode == "cz") {
$_call = 'getCzechShortDescription';
$_code == "czech_short_description";
}
if($storeCode == "de") {
$_call = 'getGermanyShortDescription';
$_code == "germany_short_description";
}
if($storeCode == "at") {
$_call = 'getGermanyShortDescription';
$_code == "germany_short_description";
}
if($storeCode == "dk") {
$_call = 'getDenmarkShortDescription';
$_code == "denmark_short_description";
}
}
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

$renderLabel = true;
if ($_attributeLabel == 'none') {
$renderLabel = false;
}

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
$_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
$_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
$_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>

<?php
$className = "";
$descriptionArray = ['short_description', 'english_short_description', 'czech_short_description', 'germany_short_description'];
if(in_array($_code, $descriptionArray)) {
$className = 'std';
}
?>
```

Any help to custom code for product name?

Answer (score -1):

Magento probably supports Product Name per store view. I think you might need to remove those useless attributes or migrate them to Product View per store.

[image]